# How to stream .wav file to websocket with Python3 (I have a working Node example)

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, audio-streaming

I'm tasked with converting a client from Node to Python for automation purposes. I've done everything so far, but I've been kind of roadblocked on the last bit which regards actually streaming the wav file to the websocket.

Here's the node example that I need to convert to python:

```
const startStreaming = () => {
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(soxTransform).pipe(wavTransform).pipe(slow.slowStream(delay))
        fileStream.on('data', (data) => {
            ws.send(data)
        })
        fileStream.on('end', () => {
            if (endStream) {
                ws.send(Buffer('\0'))
            } else {
                resolve("success")
            }
        })
    }
```

I've tried a few things, my main thought is using a generator or doing something like this:

```
def read_file(path): 
    data = open(path, 'rb')
    while data:
        sent = ws.send(data)
        if not sent:
            # The socket has disconnected if the send fails
            break
        data = data[sent:]
    ws.send(Buffer('\0'))
    ws.close()
ws.connect(host)
path = './audio.wav'
read_file(path)
```

Any insight would help, I've never had to deal with audio streaming in python nor node before, and even when I successfully send audio to the server, when I play it back on the server side it's basically just random audio.

Comment: I'm not sure what all these pipes and such are for... or why you're going from Node to Python... but I have some advice for you.  If you're streaming audio data from a server to a client, don't use Web Sockets.  Just use a regular HTTP request.  Save yourself a lot of hassle.  You can stream to it just fine.

Comment: I'm tasked with building a whole data science suite for our service. Right now our client is built in nodejs, but for automation purposes I'm rebuilding the client in python. Doing it with an http request isnt really possible for our purpose, but we've changed the game plan and we're now going to partition and upload audio files directly to the engine and bypass most of the server via post request for analysis, to avoid all of this hassle. Appreciate the feedback though!